# Custom Gallery images showing in one column

Tags: theming, media

In Drupal 7, I have created a custom gallery, but all images are showing in only one column.

I have Bootstrap theme for Drupal. I'm using the modules Views (Bootstrap), Colorbox, Multiupload Imagefield Widget, Multiupload Filefield Widget (both for multiimage uploads).

Steps I took:

1. I created a new content type Gallery
2. Added an image field to the content type and selected multiload (to enable upload of several images at once)
3. Removed body field as I only need images.
4. Image display has been set to Colorbox (I previously created different image styles - preview, full, etc.)
5. In Views, I created a new page Galleries, which contains all galleries that I have on the site. I had no problems putting those Galleries in a 4 column layout. So basically this is a Albums view.

My problem is that when I click on Album name, a new page (of content type Gallery) opens. It contains all the images of the particular album. However, all the images are shown in only one column.

I have tried to change the layout with panels and display suite, but as Images are considered as one field, the end result stays the same. Is there any way I could change the steps I took and do this differently, so I could have the Gallery with listed Albums as I have now, and then when I click on albums the images are shown in 3 or 4 column layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its has multiple ways to do that but I recommend you to do it with **views**.

Create a new views as block view and follow the following steps:

1. Add image field in **fields**
2. Add filter criteria
3. You can change the **FORMAT** of the views as you like (according to your requirement you should select **Grid type**) to display images in multiple columns.
4. Add a contextual filter with **nid** (node ID) field and set it [like this](https://snag.gy/Brp3e4.jpg)
5. Save the views and go to `admin/structure/block` and enable your block
6. Don't forget to **hide the image field in the manage display of Gallery Content Type**, path is `admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT-TYPE/display`

**Image as Example**

[image]
For more details, [click here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/views/grid-output-format)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try, though I'm trying to understand the logistics behind this solution. I have several albums, that I can show as a grid on one page (Galleries) - used Views. But when I click on specific album, it takes me to the album page. This is where the problem is. 
In point 5. you say enable your block. I only then need this block on album pages (lets say content type album). Would this work on every album page I create?

Comment: Yeah it'll work on every node of type **Gallery**.